# Get ID inside onContextItemSelected with CardsUI

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cards

I have an app which has had a `ListView` which is connected to a SQL database...
Now I want to update the app to use the CardsUI https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android

This code has been working fine until now:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DONE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo infod = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();
            long infodId = infod.id;
            Cursor items = dbAdapter.getMyItem(infodId);
            startManagingCursor(items);

            String title = items.getString(items
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
            String description = items.getString(items
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            int priority = items.getInt(items
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_PRIORITY));

            dbAdapter.updateList(infodId, priority, title,
                    description);
            return true;
        case EDIT_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo idInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();
            long idInfolong = idInfo.id;
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Detail.class);
            i.putExtra(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, idInfolong);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    menu.add(0, EDIT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_edit);
    menu.add(0, DONE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_done);
}
```

How can I use this code with the Cards? It always crashes. I read that if you manage a SQL cursor, it's connected to the MySQL. How can I get the ID of my record inside `onContextItemSelected`?

This is the my logcat output:

```
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087): Process: com.myapp.mylist, PID: 3087
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.myapp.mylist.MainActivtiy.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:395)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2620)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3864)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-22 19:28:37.213: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer

Comment: can you paste your MainActivity code ? at least your onContextItemSelected code

Comment: Yes sorry I posted my code...

Answer (score 1):

**SQL _id for onContextItemSelected()**

In `onCreateContextMenu()` Get the data of the item via the adapter.  Then attach an itent to the menu item that contains the _id for the sql row. `onContextItemSelected` now has an intent attached to the menuitem that contains the sql row _id.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            String name = adapter2.getItem(info.position).get_name();
            menu.setHeaderTitle(name);
            MenuInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menulistitem, menu);
            MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.action_context_delete);
            Intent i = new Intent();
            //put the database _id into the intent for the oncontextitemselected
            i.putExtra("id", adapter2.getItem(info.position).get_id());
            mi.setIntent(i);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_context_delete:
            Intent i = item.getIntent();
            if (i != null) {
                Bundle b = i.getExtras();
                if (b != null) {
                    int id = b.getInt("id");
                    Uri deleteIdUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            RidesDatabaseProvider.CONTENT_URI, id);
                    context.getContentResolver()
                            .delete(deleteIdUri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: had same problem and I solved it by passing _id in menuitem intent

Comment: Can you have a look at my code maybe? I don't know exactly how this would work on my code...

Comment: See how I use info.postion on getItem of the adapter for the list.  You need to at least save info.postion into an intent and then attach that intent to the menuitem.  Then in your oncontextitemselected you actually know what item was selected by the value stored in the intent.